# DC-DC converter on custom pcb: lmr14050 drops 1 volt under load

Tags: power-supply, pcb-design, circuit-design, protection

I'm trying to use the LMR14050 chip for my shield for Raspberry Pi 4 to convert 12 V to 5 V and power the RPi, also I've a MCU stm32f105r8t6, powered also from 5 V by converting to 3.3 V by linear converter. So, my problem is: when I run the system in idle mode(powered only MCU) the Vout=**4.85 V** and it's even good, but when I connected the RPi, the Vout drops down to **3.7 V**. Also, when I power up the system on some Vin lavels I get some noise from LMR and every time it's VERY hot, back side of the pcb is abou 70 - 75°C. Afterwards, Vout highly depends from Vin value. P.S. if I solder the soft-start capacitor the system would give only 0.8 V P.P.S. On the schematics resistors R9 and R10 was changed to 68k and 12k, also L1 is 3.3 μH.

Schematic:

[image]

PCB source:

[image]

Comment: What is the part number/specs for L1?

Comment: @Kartman VLS6045EX-3R3N

Comment: The diode antiparallel to the sw output and ground looks versy small for this task.

Comment: @fifi_22 1PS79SB17,115 that’s parnumber for shottky diode, even I’ll try to solder another one, and does it take any differ if it’s unparalleled to SW pin?

Comment: The diode for VD5 should rated at 6+ Amp not 30mA!  Your inductor choice is probably only good for 3A output.

Comment: @Kartman yeah I know about inductor, the system is only for 2,5 Amp max, will try to set another diode and test it again, thx

Comment: The diode with that marking is good, BUT I see that ob the pcb the diode is very small - check wit some known diode.

Comment: @Kartman I soldered 1n5822 diode and it didn't help me, Vout also depends on Vin (on 9V Vout is 2.8V, on 15V Vout is 5.2V), after adding load(rpi) it also drops the voltage to 3.8V

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally my solution is

1. Solder mbrs540t3g diode at VD5.
2. I soldered another pcb to prevent sc in pcb, defenitely it was.